# Explain Python code

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to understand below python code.

Here is my interpretation.

```
 def __init__(self):
    self.intermediate = {}
    self.result = []
```

intermediate and result are variables.
intermediate is of type dict. 
result is of type list

```
  def emit_intermediate(self, key, value):
    self.intermediate.setdefault(key, [])
    self.intermediate[key].append(value)
```

If key is in the dictionary intermediate then return its value from this method. (Will this line : self.intermediate[key].append(value) still get executed if the value is returned ?)
If the key is not in the dictionary insert a key with a value of an empty list into the dictionary intermediate.
If a key has been inserted then append the value to the list associated with the key.

```
def emit(self, value):
    self.result.append(value)
```

append the value to the result list

here is the entire code :

```
  def __init__(self):
        self.intermediate = {}
        self.result = []

    def emit_intermediate(self, key, value):
        self.intermediate.setdefault(key, [])
        self.intermediate[key].append(value)

    def emit(self, value):
        self.result.append(value)
```

Comment: "If key is in the dictionary intermediate then return its value from this method." - there's no `return` statement there.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.intermediate.setdefault(key, [])
```

Tells you what the value of the key will be if it is not present yet.
So if you insert a key that is not in `self.intermediate` it will create a new entry with that key and gives it the value `[]`.

Then the next line "`self.intermediate[key].append(value)`" (that is always executed) always has a list that it can append to; either a new one from `self.intermediate.setdefault(key, [])` or a previously created one.

So:

```
someobjectofthisclass.emit_intermediate("foo", 1)
print(someobjectofthisclass.intermediate)
>> {"foo":[1]}

someobjectofthisclass.emit_intermediate("foo", 1)
someobjectofthisclass.emit_intermediate("foo", 2)
someobjectofthisclass.emit_intermediate("bar", 1)
print(someobjectofthisclass.intermediate)
>> {"foo":[1,1,2], "bar":[1]}
```